# Proper UIGestureRecognizer and Delegate design

Tags: ios, uiview, uigesturerecognizer, gesture, uicontrol

This is a pretty hypothetical question just to understand proper design but lets say I have two custom UIViews.

One of them is essentially a container that I'll call a drawer. Its purpose is to hide and show content. It's a lot like the notification center on iOS where you swipe to pull it open and flick it back up to close it. It's a generic container than can contain any other UIView. It has a UIPanGestureRecognizer to track the finger that's pulling it open/closed. It might also have a UISwipeGestureRecognizer to detect a "flick".

The other view is a custom map widget that has UIPan/Rotation/Pinch GestureRecognizers.

I think the drawer view should be the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate for the Pan/Swipe GestureRecognizers so that it can prevent touches from being delivered unless the user is grabbing "the handle".

My first instinct is for the map to be the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate of the pan/rotation/pinch gestures so that it can allow them to all run simultaneously.

The problem I'm having is that, I really don't want the map to receive any touches or begin recognizing gestures until the drawer is completely open. I'd like to be able to enforce this behavior automatically in the drawer itself so that it works for all subviews right out of the box.

The only way that I can think to do this is to wire all of the gestures handlers to the ViewController and let it do everything, but to me that breaks encapsulation as now it has to know that the map gestures need to run simultaneously, that the drawer should only get touches on it's handle and that the map should only get touches when it's open.

What are some ways of doing this where the logic can stay in the Views where I think it belongs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this to make the subviews of the drawer disabled while panning. Essentially loop through the drawer's subviews and disbale interaction on them.

```
[self.subviews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIView *subview, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
    subview.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
}];
```

And something similar again for when you want to re-enable user interaction on the subviews.

Comment: I can't argue that this solution wouldn't work, but it's outside of the available gesture tools. Is that because there is no proper way for Superviews to control their Subviews gesture behavior (aside from being a delegate)?

Answer (score 0):

This should already Just Work™. A gesture recogniser is attached to a view; when a continuous gesture is recognised, all subsequent touches associated with that gesture are associated with that view.

So in your case, when the drawer pan is recognised, no touches associated with that pan should ever cause behaviour in your map view's pan/pinch/rotation gestures (unless you explicitly specify that they should using the appropriate delegate methods).

Or do you mean that you want to prevent the user from, halfway through opening the drawer, using another finger (i.e. another gesture) to start scrolling the (half-visible) map? If so, you should just set `userInteractionEnabled` on the drawer's `contentView` (or equivalent) to `NO` at `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan`/`Changed` and `YES` again at `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded`/`Cancelled`.

Comment: The actual use case is that the drawer is in the process of moving (without a touch) because of the velocity it was given from a previous finger drag/flick...then, the user goes to stop the drawer from moving and touches the map (the child) which activates the map's drag...so instead of stopping the drawer from closing, they pan the map and drawer continues to close. It sounds like your 3rd paragraph is more applicable and you're suggesting something very similar to what lramirez135 did in his answer. This seems to make sense so I think i need to give him credit. But thank you for clarifying.